# Trigger on a specific date SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, events

I'd like to know if is it possible to trigger a delete on a table, if a date of a row is less than current date?

For example

```
ID      token     Expiration_date
---------------------------
1      fkjeorf  2017/05/15 14:05:00
2      gdgrhjj  2017/05/16 13:05:00
3      mojkkut  2017/05/17 18:05:00
```

If we are on the 2017/05/17 18:00:00, then the two first rows are auto deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a job to delete the records (using SQL Server Agent).

I would recommend that you simply use a view so the data is always accurate:

```
create view v_example_actives as
    select e.*
    from example e
    where expiration_date < getdate();
```

Personally, I prefer to keep all the rows in the table (for future analysis).  But, you can periodically delete rows at a convenient time.  Users of the view will never see expired accounts.